# How to instruct Closure Compiler not to rename/remove a local variable?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment, google-closure-compiler

In the following code, I need the variable `some_var` not to be renamed or removed by Google's Closure Compiler.

```
function scopedEval(code){
    var some_var = 'world' ;
    return eval('('+code+')') ;
}
scopedEval('alert("hello, "+some_var)') ;
```

The code to be eval-ed relies on the existence of a few variables, so I need them to be left untouched.

How can I instruct Closure Compiler to do that?

**PS:**
Please disregard the issue about the use of `eval` being a bad practice. That's another matter entirely.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some Closure Compiler options allowing this sort of thing specifically, but failing that, I would tackle the problem one of these two ways:

## Option 1

Create a global object to store your variables, and then use the `js_externs` option to prevent it from being munged:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @js_externs vars
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
vars = {};
```

Then you can apply string properties to this object that should be left untouched

```
function scopedEval(code){
    vars['some_var'] = 'world';
    return eval('('+code+')');
}
scopedEval('alert("hello, "+vars["some_var"])');
```

## Option 2

If for some reason `vars['some_var']` won't work for you and you need to use `some_var` literally inside the `eval`ed code, then you can use `with` to get around this. In this case, you don't need to declare `vars` as an extern.

```
function scopedEval(code){
    var vars = {
      "some_var": "world"
    };
    with(vars) {
      return eval('('+code+')');
    }
}
scopedEval('alert("hello, "+some_var)');
```

I'll leave it up to your discretion whether or not you feel dirty using the two features of JavaScript that attract the most vitriol together, namely `with` and `eval`.

Comment: No problem with the `with` statement. You just have to know how to use it safely. I'll keep looking for a way to do it without changing the code, though.

Comment: Another option is to use the function constructor:

new Function("code", "return eval('('+code+')');");

Comment: `with` statement produce the error: The `with` statement cannot be used in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the function constructor:

```
var scopedEval = new Function(
    "code", 
    "var some_var = 'world'; return eval('('+code+')');");
```

Comment: @GetFree closure-compiler doesn't change strings so the function constructor will remain unchanged during compilation.

Comment: That's the same as using `with({'some_var' : 'world'})`. The string `'some_var'` is not changed.

Comment: 'with' can't be used with strict mode or ES6 modules, while function constructors can.

Comment: Good point, it's phasing out. You forgot to add the variable in the function definition, though.